# HTTPS redirects back to HTTP sometimes

Tags: .htaccess

Weird issue happens, need help.

I have the URL:

```
https://example.com/sslTest?bbb=&eeee=1
```

In some like random moments if I hit enter on browser URL bar it redirects to HTTP:

```
http://example.com/sslTest?bbb=&eeee=1
```

I'm using chrome:

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php

Options -Indexes
```

Everything worked all the time and nothing seems to be changed to affect this. 
Also interesting fact is if I remove query it redirects back to page and HTTPS.

I tried to add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What could be the problem?
Page returns error `400`.

**EDIT:** Also the same issue happens if i add url query to even empty php file

Comment: "if i hit enter on browser url bar it redirects to HTTP" - Is this actually a "redirect" (what HTTP status are you seeing in the network traffic)? Or is this simply selected from Chrome's auto-completing Omnibox (ie. the browser URL bar)? Presumably you had nothing to force HTTPS (before the other directives you "tried to add") so HTTP and HTTPS are both valid? Where did you add the other directives you mention? Do you get the 400 status only after adding those other directives?

Comment: there is a lack of information here.  httpd.conf and ssl.conf are necessary to evalutate why the errors are there.

Comment: @MrWhite i m bit confused. .. Imagine i m browsing my website (all is good) and then just to refresh page i hit enter on url in url bar and boooms from HTTPS it goes to HTTP for no valid reason

Comment: What if, instead of hitting "Enter" in the URL bar, you hit the browser "Refresh" button or "F5"? Or even "Ctrl+F5" (which bypasses the browser cache)?

Comment: @MrWhite It stays on http and still show error 400

Comment: I heard that it could be that page loads faster than SSL. .. Could that be case?

Comment: Interesting is that not all the time redirect to HTTP happens. .. It is like random thing

Comment: 1. Check your code there might be mix content problem, somewhere url exist with http. 2. If you are using database check it for http entry

Comment: Thanks for answer but I think you did not read the question. ..

Comment: Please try to make a snapshot of such a `redirect`using the devtools of your browser.

Comment: Also the same issue happens if i add url query to even empty php file

Comment: Does this "falling back" to http also happen in the incognito mode of Chrome?

Comment: @user188737 Yep :(

Comment: Just noticed something very strange with the new fangled www hiding Chrome. If I am on a www.something.tld site and I hit enter in the address bar it actually requests something.tld instead of www.something.tld. May be related to this.

Comment: @user188737 I do no think so. That just seems like redirect from www to domain.. But thanks!

Comment: No there is no server redirect in my case, the other way around actually. If domain.tld is different in setup to www.domain.tld, there may be your problem. If you first let the address bar expand your url and then hit enter, does it also happen then?

Comment: @user188737 Nope url remains the same just `HTTPS` changes to `HTTP`

Comment: Then you need to look at the network tab of the developer tools and establish there is actually a redirect coming from the server.

Comment: @user188737 how no idea how to use it and see if redirect happened. .. All i see console clears showing my url and status is 400

Comment: You need to turn on "preserve log" and look for a response with a 301-307 status code.

Comment: @user188737 I have only error `302` for favicon

Comment: 302 is not an error, it is a relocation to another url. Kind of strange for favicon. In the headers you will see a Location in the Response headers.

Comment: @user188737 It sends it to `404.php` as there are no favicon. ..

Comment: Ok, well if that suits then that can stay. Does it relocate to https though? If there is no 30x status coming from the server, then it must be Chrome itself doing this. Either from cache or through some loaded extension. Incognito mode somewhat rules out cache. Maybe there is something important in the Console tab of the developer tools also.

Comment: The `error code 400` means you have a bad syntax in your redirection statement. My bet it is due to the part about `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`. Please add a forward slash like: `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}`. Does that help?

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard Hey, thanks for comment, but seems that is not it

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard The `REQUEST_URI` server variable already includes the slash prefix, so if you add an additional slash in the _substitution string_ you'll get a double slash in the resulting redirect - which is not desirable.

Comment: "It stays on http and still show error 400" - But before hitting F5 you were presumably on HTTPS and it wasn't showing a 400 response?! Do you only get the 400 (Bad Request) response after adding the HTTP to HTTPS redirect directives? If there is _something_ that is redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP the adding a redirect in the other direction is likely to result in an error condition (eg. an endless loop) However, as @user188737 has already pointed out... there doesn't appear to be any evidence here that there is a 3xx external redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite As i told error 400 ONLY appears when i hit enter on link (inside browser url bar). .. I can without any issues surf site around with mouse clicks (or any refresh) and nothing bad will happen. .. But if i hit enter error 400 sometimes comes. .. Then if i refresh it is already on `HTTP` and stays there with error 400 no matter what!

Comment: @MrWhite But if i remove query like `http://example.com/sslTest` it redirects to `HTTPS`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the condition is not matching the request you are trying to re-route to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php

Options -Indexes
```

From the docs:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

`The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.`

The `RewriteCond` do not match the request in an `AND` fashion:

`http://example.com/sslTest?bbb=&eeee=1`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

So likely the RewriteRule does not apply in for this request.

---

Even though it might be matching, as REQUEST_FILENAME could eventually be resolved first to some file which is containing a `.php` ending. Without the full configuration this cannot be verified. And I assume that this is not the case in your setup.

From the docs `REQUEST_FILENAME`:

```
The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request,
if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME
is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as
REQUEST_URI. Depending on the value of AcceptPathInfo, the server may have only used 
some leading components of the REQUEST_URI to map the request to a file.
```

Comment: If i add `.php` nothing changes

Comment: Adding `.php` will run into another error because the rewrite looks like this: `RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]`
Which means, it matches anything `.*` that comes in. With `()` it additionally captures it in backreference group 1. For example `sslTest.php` is requested, so it is fully matched and placed into backreference group 1. Then it is rewritten to `$1\.php` which will result in `sslTest.php.php`.

Comment: @hargut That would only occur if `sslTest.php.php` existed on the filesystem (the first condition - which will fail and the rewrite does not occur). Besides, this would only result in a 404, it doesn't explain the OPs apparent scenario of a HTTPS to HTTP "redirect".

Comment: Indeed, that is true. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want HTTPS enabled for all URIs, then keep it simple like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The condition is: If https is not enabled.

And the rewrite rule is match anything in the uri and send it to its https counterpart.

Comment: No change again :(

Comment: can it be something with SSL certificate? This same .htaccess file works for other sites and no similar issue was found on other sites

Comment: This is really no different (and arguably more complex) than the code already posted in the question?

Comment: Is the `DocumentRoot` for the web server running on port 80 and port 443 the same? My example should be in the DocumentRoot for port 80 as it is the textbook example for redirect everything to HTTPS. Google "redirect always to https" and the example will show up everywhere.